# ActiveReports <LI> tag spacing

Tags: activereports

I've a rich textbox in activereports detail section. Its assigned with html dyanmicaly. That HTML includes LIST tags too(UL and LI). But the problem I cant change the spacing between each LI tags. I tried all CSS methods on the LI's style property. Like Margin, Padding , Line height. But nothing helped me to solve that issue. But I need some noticeable spacing between each LI tags on the Richtextbox..

This is an emergency requirement from my boss.

Requesting your valuable support..
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

There are list of [supported HTML elements and CSS style attributes in the ActiveReports documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20110518062342/http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/arCONRichText.html). You could look through that reference and try the mentioned style attributes. I'd try the line-height, margin, and padding properties of the LI elements. Or maybe try putting a P element on one of the LI elements? If that doesn't work you should probably contact [ActiveReports Support at ComponentOne](https://web.archive.org/web/20110924082400/http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SupportServices/Overview/).

If nothing else, you could try to get some RTF document to look the way you want (i.e. increased spacing between list items) and try importing that RTF document into ActiveReports instead.

Comment: Hi scott.. I tried all the above method. But unfortunately nothing worked. So I tried inserting a <br> tag which makes more gap, but that was quiet adjustable for my client..

Comment: @sforsandeep: Glad to know you figured something out. If you have a solution, then I encourage you you to answer your own question here and mark it as the answer. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me:

The paragraph tag supports the inline style attribute in an ActiveReports RichTextBox.  So you can enclose each list item within open/close paragraph tags, and then use margin-top, margin-bottom in the inline paragraph style to get the line spacing how you want it.

I used style='margin-top:0;margin-bottom:5'